# hive.cli.print.header=true not working

Tags: hive

I'm trying to export the results of a query to the file system.  Everything works fine, except that I can't get the column headers as part of the file.
Here's what my script looks like:

```
set hive.cli.print.header=true;
set mapreduce.task.timeout=0;
set hive.auto.convert.join=false;
set hive.execution.engine=tez;

insert overwrite local directory '/work/output'
ROW FORMAT DELIMTED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'

select...
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Not supported. You can spool the results from the CLI including the headers but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: In other words: `hive.cli` is for the command-line interface (CLI) a.k.a. legacy fat client, and `print` is for console display. Ignored by the SQL query processor on server side.

Answer (score 6):

if you use hive cli the below command should give you the file with column name as header.

```
hive -S -e "set hive.cli.print.header=true;select * from a1;" >out101.text
```